# Basic question about isomorphism of $O_X$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. Suppose I have two $O_X$-modules $F$ and $G$ and a homomorphism $\psi: F \to G$. As sheaves of rings on $X$ we know that $\psi$ is an isomorphism if and only if 
$\psi_x: F_x \to G_x$ is an isomorphism. What is the equivalent statement if I want $\psi$ to be an isomorphism of $O_X$-modules? Thank you.

Comment: It's the same statement with the same proof. This should be covered in any book which introduces sheaves.

Comment: What I was wondering was $\psi_x$ has to be an isomorphism of `something' and  what this 'something' is. I think it should be either $O_X(X)$-modules or $O_{X,x}$-modules...

Comment: $\psi_x$ is a morphism of $O_{X,x}$ modules